# Count how many files have string

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

This is an assignment so please just point me in the right direction.

I have a bunch of files of messages. Each message is addressed to somebody so every file will contain a string like "To: John Smith", "To: Jane Doe"....

I want to count how many files are addressed to each person and print it

I know we can count how many files contain a name with

```
grep -lr "name" directoryPath | wc -l
```

**The Problem:**

I am not sure how to find each unique recipient before counting their messages.

I was thinking I can maybe make a temp file to store the names and count so I can check back each time if the recipient is new. Im sure there's a better way though

Comment: Read the manpages for the  `sort` and `uniq` programs. Think about how they can work with the results of using grep to extract the address lines from all of the files.

Comment: You can use `grep`, `sort`, and `uniq` to complete this exercise. `uniq` can give you the final result if you use the correct flag.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to know the number of _messages_ per recipient rather than the number of files per recipient. So instead of grepping each individual file, I would recommend to concatenate the files and focus on the number of matching `To:` lines.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Concatenation is not needed when you `grep "$To" directoryPath/*` as the first step.

Comment: IMHO with `To: a@test.com; b@test.com; a@test.com` in a file, this file should be counted once for both `a` and `b`, but that is being perfect.  Supporting this situation is less trivial than only sorting and counting the `grep` results.
This is why examples (as asked by @Cyrus ) are so important: When all input files only have one addressee in the `To` line, the solution is much easier.

Comment: @WalterA Concatenation makes a difference when counting occurrences across multiple files (to get rid of the annoying filename prefix). But you do have a point; `grep -h` can accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments you received have what you need to answer this assignment.  Here's how to put them together:

```
grep -hr To: directoryPath | sort  | uniq -c
```

The grep will search all files in directoryPath and below for lines containing "To:" and display them.   The -r instructs grep to search all directories recursively and the -h suppresses the filenames in grep's output.

We have to use sort to put all the same names together.  This sets up the output to be counted by uniq -c (which requires the input to be sorted to achieve your requirements).

Try the above command without the pipes to get a feel for what the output is.  For instance, try this:

```
grep -r To: directoryPath
```

And compare it to this:

```
grep -hr To: directoryPath
```

Then try to see what happens with uniq -c without the sort:

```
grep -hr To: directoryPath | uniq -c
```

Or try the unique function of sort and see how that impacts the results:

```
grep -hr To: directoryPath | sort  -u
```

In short, if you care about learning the material, play with the various parameters and see why the answer works.

By the way, I haven't tested my answers to you.  Most posters present their questions with test data and example expected results.  Then posters can confirm that their solutions answer the question properly.  In this case, I'm just giving you my educated guess as to what you need.